# Generate all permutations numbers that add up to four including decimals of .5 and .25 in an array

Tags: javascript, math, random, numbers

I am trying to randomly generate rhythms. I need to randomly select an array of numbers that add up to 4, only with whole numbers or with decimals that end in .5 or .25, not including zero. example: [0.5, 2, 1.25, 0.25]. I originally tried to write down all the permutations, but once i decided to include the decimal ones i realized it would take awhile and there would probably be a way to generate them. here was the original code by writing the permutations without decimals.

```js
var permutations = [
  [1, 1, 1, 1],
  [1, 1, 2],
  [1, 2, 1],
  [2, 1, 1],
  [2, 2],
  [3, 1],
  [1, 3],
  [4]
];

let getRandomArray = function() {
  return permutations[Math.floor(Math.random() * permutations.length)];
}

console.log(getRandomArray());
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create all possible combinations and pick a random array.

```js
function get4() {

    function iter(temp) {
        return function (v) {
            const
                t = temp.concat(v),
                s = t.reduce(add);

            if (s >= 4) {
                if (s === 4) result.push(t);
                return;
            }
            values.forEach(iter(t));
        };
    }
    
    const
        add = (a, b) => a + b,
        values = [
          0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 1,
          1.25, 1.5, 1.75, 2,
          2.25, 2.5, 2.75, 3,
          3.25, 3.5, 3.75, 4
        ],
        result = [];

    values.forEach(iter([]));
    return result;
}

console.log(get4().map(a => a.join(' ')));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Some comments as to what is going on would be just lovely :)

Comment: i can not do prosa today, sorry.